# Website does not display on android 4.0

Tags: android, html, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've been working on launching a custom design for this music blog I'm working on and I'm experiencing some troubles with the Android 4.0 browser.

It works fine on Android 2.x (and every other browser I've tried) but when I try to load it on a device running 4.1 or higher (browserstack emulator) the page loads and all of the text, graphics, etc disappear. The only things that show up are SoundCloud embeds.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here? What changed from 4.0 to 4.1 with the browser that is rendering my website useless on the new devices?

http://chune.me/

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Boiled the problem down to my CSS reset... if anybody has an idea what is causing it in here I'd love to know. I just decided to use a new one... Strange.

```
/**
 * reset.css
 *
 * Adapted from:
 * Normalize.css by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/
 * HTML5 boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/
 * HTML5 Doctor Reset by Eric Meyer and Richard Clark: html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/
 *
 * Modified by Elliot Jay Stocks
 */

html, 
body, 
div, 
span, 
object, 
iframe, 
h1, 
h2, 
h3, 
h4, 
h5, 
h6, 
p, 
blockquote, 
pre, 
abbr, 
address, 
cite, 
code, 
del, 
dfn, 
em, 
img, 
ins, 
kbd, 
q, 
samp, 
small, 
strong, 
sub, 
sup, 
var, 
b, 
i, 
dl, 
dt, 
dd, 
ol, 
ul, 
li, 
fieldset, 
form, 
label, 
legend, 
table, 
caption, 
tbody, 
tfoot, 
thead, 
tr, 
th, 
td, 
article, 
aside, 
canvas, 
details, 
figcaption, 
figure, 
footer, 
header, 
hgroup, 
menu, 
nav, 
section, 
summary, 
time, 
mark, 
audio, 
video                                                   { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent; }        

article, 
aside, 
details, 
figcaption, 
figure, 
footer, 
header, 
hgroup, 
nav, 
section                                                 { display: block; }

audio, 
canvas, 
video                                                   { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }

audio:not([controls])                                   { display: none; }

[hidden]                                                { display: none; }

html                                                    { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body                                                    { margin: 0; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight:normal; }          

a                                                       { color:blue; }

a:focus                                                 { outline: thin dotted; }

li                                                      { list-style:none; }

abbr[title]                                             { border-bottom:none; }

b, 
strong                                                  { font-weight: 700; }

i,
em,
dfn                                                     { font-style: italic; }

hr                                                      { display: block; height: 1px; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }

ins                                                     { background: #ff9; color: #000; text-decoration: none; }

mark                                                    { background: #ff0; color: #000; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; }

pre, 
code, 
kbd, 
samp                                                    { font-family: monospace, monospace; _font-family: 'courier new', monospace; }

pre                                                     { white-space: pre; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }

q                                                       { quotes: none; }

q:before, 
q:after                                                 { content: ""; content: none; }

small                                                   { font-size: 85%; }

sub, 
sup                                                     { font-size: 75%; line-height: 0; position: relative; vertical-align: baseline; }

sup                                                     { top: -0.5em; }

sub                                                     { bottom: -0.25em; }

img                                                     { border: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; vertical-align: middle; }

label                                                   { cursor: pointer; }

input, 
select, 
textarea                                                { font-size: 100%; margin: 0; vertical-align: baseline; *vertical-align: middle; }

button, 
input                                                   { line-height: normal; *overflow: visible; }

button, 
input[type="button"], 
input[type="reset"], 
input[type="submit"]                                    { cursor: pointer; -webkit-appearance: button; }

input[type="checkbox"], 
input[type="radio"]                                     { box-sizing: border-box; }

input[type="search"]                                    { -webkit-appearance: textfield; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration         { -webkit-appearance: none; }

button::-moz-focus-inner, 
input::-moz-focus-inner                                 { border: 0; padding: 0; }

textarea                                                { overflow: auto; vertical-align: top; resize: vertical; }

table                                                   { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }

td                                                      { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: Further testing shows it is working on the Kindle Fire 2 running 4.0, Kindle Fire HD 8.9 running 4.0, Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 on 4.0, Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 on 4.0

Comment: Does _not_ display correctly on: Samsung Galaxy S III (4.1), Samsung Galaxy Note II (4.1), LG Nexus 4 (4.2), Motorola Razr Maxx HD (4.1).

Comment: Tried disabling JS on a 4.1 device and there is no effect. Has to be something with the HTML or CSS.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` has no effect either.

Comment: So I deleted all the CSS for a minute and the content does not disappear. Going to investigate this further.

Comment: Note sure the following will help, because I had the inverse problem: a `div` disappears on 4.0.3, but not on 4.1., due to use of `overflow-y: scroll`: The problem surfaces once the content is indeed too tall for a `div` that has a fixed height assigned. Curiously, it is the `div` immediately _above_ that disappears.